# The Angel at the Akeida

Tags: malach-angel, vayera, binding-of-isaac

[Braishis 22:12](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8217)

וַיֹּאמֶר אַל תִּשְׁלַח יָדְךָ אֶל הַנַּעַר וְאַל תַּעַשׂ לוֹ מְאוּמָה כִּי | עַתָּה יָדַעְתִּי כִּי יְרֵא אֱלֹהִים אַתָּה וְלֹא חָשַׂכְתָּ אֶת בִּנְךָ אֶת יְחִידְךָ **מִמֶּנִּי** translates as: And he said, "Do not stretch forth your hand to the lad, nor do the slightest thing to him, for now I know that you are a God fearing man, and you did not withhold your son, your only one, **from Me**.

Now what exactly is the angel saying over here "from me"? Avraham did not withhold Yitzchok from Hashem, not from the angel?

Comment: this presumes that the speaker in pasuk 12 was the angel who spoke in 22:11. The way it is presented in rashi, the entire of pasuk 12 was said by hashem.

Comment: Not a duplicate question. Good question.

Answer (score 3):

As agents of G-d, *malachim* speak on His behalf. This is also the case with prophets. (Conversely, we also find language in Tanach indicating that G-d is the One actually being addressed when an angel is being spoken to.)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is a different angel than the one for the actual akeida. That angel was the Satan. And when Avraham successfully completed the test, that angel gave a reward. This second angel is speaking directly for HaShem and gives a second reward. As it points out in midrash, the test was instituted between the Satan and HaShem. Two parties to the test, two rewards.

Answer (score 0):

[Seforno](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=1&perek=22&mefaresh=sforno) interprets the term **ממני** in conection with *yreh Hashem*, meaning that the malach knew that Avraham was superior to him (therefore, *than I*) in fear of Hashem (not in connection with the withhold of Yitzchok from Hashem):

> **מִמֶּנִּי**. שֶׁאַתָּה יְרֵא אֱלהִים יותֵר מִמֶּנִּי שֶׁאֲנִי מַלְאָךְ,
>   וְרָאוּי לְמַעֲלָה יותֵר מִמֶּנִּי, כְּאָמְרָם זִכְרונָם לִבְרָכָה:
>   גְּדולִים צַדִּיקִים וְכוּ', שֶׁאַתָּה בְּפעַל יְרֵא אֱלהִים, כְּמו
>   שֶׁהָיָה הָאֵל יודֵעַ קדֶם לָכֵן שֶׁהָיִיתָ יְרֵא אֱלהִים בְּכחַ,
>   וְתִפּל יְדִיעָתו הַפּועֶלֶת עַל הַנִּמְצָא בְּפעַל.